# Reset a form with jquery using specific selector

Tags: jquery, html, jquery-selectors, form-submit

I have a form like this:

```
<form id='formid'>

<input type='text' name='textname'>
<input type='button' id='resetbutton'>

</form>
```

Now I want to jquery code which submit a form with `id=formid` when a button`(id='resetbutton' in id=formid form)` is clicked. And I want it to also run in IE7.

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use the native reset button:

```
<input type="reset" value=" Reset ">
```

and extend it with jquery:

```
$('#formid').children('input[type="reset"]').click(function() {
//do what you want
};
```

Comment: oohh, I should have remembered the children function... nice one.

Answer (score 1):

```
$("#resetbutton").click(function(){
   $("#formid").submit()
});
```

this will set the click event on the button and submit the form when it's executed.

Comment: Note that I'm not 100% sure of this being IE7 compatible. but knowing how compatible jQuery is with different browsers I believe this to be no problem at all

Comment: It will work for all `#resetbutton` butons. But I want to do it only for a button(`#resetbutton`) in form(`#formid`).

Comment: It might be a good idea to keep id's unique, if you want different buttons do do different things, why give them the same id? You could just add an 'onclick' argument to the button in the html telling it to execute a specific method which then calls the '$("#formid").submit()' function.

Answer (score 0):

```
(function () {
    var $formObject = $("#formid").eq(0);

    $("#resetbutton", $formObject.get(0)).click(function (){
          $formObject.submit();
    });
})();
```